# libsvm on PyBrain on OSX for an SVM

Tags: python, macos, svm, libsvm, pybrain

For almost all day now I have been trying to make an SVM on PyBrain but it gives "Cannot find LIBSVM installation. Make sure svm.py and svmc.* are in the PYTHONPATH!"

I have OSX 10.7.5 and python 2.7.2
Separately, I went and downloaded libsvm and I followed the instruction of doing the Make. Basically unzipped it, and did the make one time in the main dir and one time in the python folder. Then I moved it to the python library folder.

Still no good. 
Can anyone help? Has anyone done an SVM with PyBrain? I cannot even get their own example to run.

Thanks

Comment: I Traced the issue to the svmtrainer.py    such that   when it tries to import cross_validation from svm it freaks out, I think that is not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

LibSVM doesn't support cross_validation any more.

https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/issues/97

Answer (score 0):

use libsvm version 2.91 -> python_old in your exportpath
https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/releases

Comment: Please give some details.