# How to install libsvm for python on mac?

Tags: python, pycharm, homebrew, libsvm

**UPDATE**: 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918574/libsvm-on-pybrain-on-osx-for-an-svm?rq=1) seems pertinent:

*libsvm (which svmtrainer needs to import) doesnt support `cross_validation` anymore.* 
Though im still not sure why i cant install libsvm to the non homebrewed python.

---

My python installation (which is at /Library/Frameworks..)
cannot seem to recognise `libsvm` no matter what i try.
But my brew install at usr/local/bin/brew has it installed fine.
How do i get the former to see the latter version?

I am trying to get it installed so i can use it in PyBrain in PyCharm.
Currently trying to test [this svm code](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/examples/supervised/neuralnets%2Bsvm/example_svm.py) so that i can run a multi-class SVM classification.
But my Python cant find it:

```
    raise ImportError("Cannot find LIBSVM installation. Make sure svm.py and svmc.* are in the PYTHONPATH!")
ImportError: Cannot find LIBSVM installation. Make sure svm.py and svmc.* are in the PYTHONPATH!
```

So I tried [this](http://codexpython.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/installing-libsvm-30-for-python-on-osx.html) but it didnt work..

If i just download the source for libsvm and then try to `make` i get

```
make -C .. lib
if [ "Darwin" = "Darwin" ]; then \
        SHARED_LIB_FLAG="-dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name,libsvm.so.2"; \
    else \
        SHARED_LIB_FLAG="-shared -Wl,-soname,libsvm.so.2"; \
    fi; \
    c++ ${SHARED_LIB_FLAG} svm.o -o libsvm.so.2
```

I also tried [installing scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755130/how-to-setup-libsvm-for-python) but the installation failed. 
I also have a package installed at collective.recipe.libsvm but im not sure how to import it.
Any ideas how to get my Python to recognise libsvm?

Answer (score 1):

This was the issue:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918574/libsvm-on-pybrain-on-osx-for-an-svm?rq=1) seems pertinent:

*libsvm (which svmtrainer needs to import) doesnt support `cross_validation` anymore.* 
Though im still not sure why i cant install libsvm to the non homebrewed python.

I am able to import libsvm from svmutil in other scripts.